# Seaborn plots for two columns of two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

There are 2 different data frames with identical column names and I would like to draw plots with Seaborn using the below statement.

However, I receive an error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'get'.

```
sns.JointGrid(data=[df_1, df_2] , x=df_1['ABC'], y=df_f2['ABC'], xlim=(140, 190), ylim=(40, 100), height=5)
```

Comment: please provide sample data.

Comment: I think you can omit this part of your code: `data=[df_1, df_2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I do not believe you can pass a list of dataframes to the `data` parameter, so you would have to concat the dataframes first OR just call the columns from the separate dataframes*

Also, when you use the `data` parameter with `seaborn`, you should only list the names of the columns for `x` and `y`. However, in this case, you are trying to plot two columns from two separate dataframes. So, it is better to omit the `data` parameter (i.e remove `data=[df_1, df_2]`).

```
sns.JointGrid(x=df_1['ABC'], y=df_f2['ABC'], xlim=(140, 190), ylim=(40, 100), height=5)
```

If you merge the columns into dataframe with different names, then you could do:

```
sns.JointGrid(data=df_1 , x='ABC_x', y='ABC_y', xlim=(140, 190), ylim=(40, 100), height=5)
```

But, the first approach makes sense in your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, the first solution you have provided worked out as well.

Comment: Hi.. I have tried accept the solution, but it says " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Even though I have clicked on the up button, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Veys you are tyring to "upvote". That is different than accepting an answer as a solution. Look for the checkmark logo next to my answer and click that. Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235